# how can i debug the hipster As a “main” Java class

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

how can i **debug** the hipster As a “main” Java class

with https://jhipster.github.io/development/

From my IDE, right-click on the “Application” class at the root of the Java package hierarchy, and run it successfully:

```
 ....   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath core/3.2.2/metrics-core-3.2.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-annotation/3.2.2/metrics-annotation-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/bundles/json/20090211_1/json-20090211_1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-afterburner/2.8.8/jackson-module-afterburner-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.195/h2-1.4.195.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.7.0/springfox-swagger2-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.13/swagger-annotations-1.5.13.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.13/swagger-models-1.5.13.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.7.0/springfox-spi-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.7.0/springfox-core-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.7.0/springfox-schema-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.7.0/springfox-swagger-common-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.7.0/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.11/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-bean-validators/2.7.0/springfox-bean-validators-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j/2.0.0/liquibase-slf4j-2.0.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/ryantenney/metrics/metrics-spring/3.1.3/metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.0/HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.42/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-envers/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-envers-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.5.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-jdk8-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.15/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.15/tomcat-juli-8.5.15.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.6.6/byte-buddy-1.6.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.25/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.25/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.11/groovy-2.4.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-websocket-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-websocket/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-websocket-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.7.0/jjwt-0.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/net/logstash/logback/logstash-logback-encoder/4.9/logstash-logback-encoder-4.9.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-core/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-core-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-heroku-connector/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-heroku-connector-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-data/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-data-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-messaging/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-messaging-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/alibaba/druid/1.1.2/druid-1.1.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-undertow/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-undertow-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.4.15.Final/undertow-core-1.4.15.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-api/3.3.6.Final/xnio-api-3.3.6.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.6.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-servlet/1.4.15.Final/undertow-servlet-1.4.15.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/1.4.15.Final/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.4.15.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/websocket/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec/1.1.0.Final/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.0/javax.el-3.0.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.sgcc.pms.api.ApiApp
Ignoring Class-Path entry lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar found in/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar as /Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar does not exist
10:56:58.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
2017-08-09 10:57:01.023 DEBUG 6011 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2017-08-09 10:57:02.891 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.pms.api.config.AsyncConfiguration    : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-08-09 10:57:03.290 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.pms.api.config.MetricsConfiguration  : Registering JVM gauges
2017-08-09 10:57:03.335 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.pms.api.config.MetricsConfiguration  : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-08-09 10:57:04.168 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering CORS filter
2017-08-09 10:57:04.346  INFO 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-08-09 10:57:04.347 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-08-09 10:57:04.350 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-08-09 10:57:04.350 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-08-09 10:57:04.354 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Initialize H2 console
2017-08-09 10:57:04.355  INFO 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Web application fully configured
2017-08-09 10:57:04.883 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.p.api.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : Configuring Liquibase
2017-08-09 10:57:04.892  WARN 6011 --- [ api-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-08-09 10:57:06.125 DEBUG 6011 --- [ api-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 1233 ms
2017-08-09 10:57:11.173 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-08-09 10:57:11.178 DEBUG 6011 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 4 ms
2017-08-09 10:57:12.179  INFO 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.ApiApp                  : Started ApiApp in 13.341 seconds (JVM running for 14.043)
2017-08-09 10:57:12.180  INFO 6011 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.ApiApp                  : 
----------------------------------------------------------
Application 'api' is running! Access URLs:
Local: http://localhost:8080
External: http://192.168.43.193:8080
Profile(s): [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

but when i debug it,it can’t show the 8080 port:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50015', transport: 'socket'    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlibjdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49760,suspend=y,server=n -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachinjvm/3.2.2/metrics-jvm-3.2.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-servlet/3.2.2/metrics-servlet-3.2.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-servlets/3.2.2/metrics-servlets-3.2.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-healthchecks/3.2.2/metrics-healthchecks-3.2.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/papertrail/profiler/1.0.2/profiler-1.0.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5/2.8.8/jackson-datatype-hibernate5-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.8/jackson-core-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hppc/2.8.8/jackson-datatype-hppc-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.7.1/hppc-0.7.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.8.8/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-json-org/2.8.8/jackson-datatype-json-org-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/bundles/json/20090211_1/json-20090211_1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-afterburner/2.8.8/jackson-module-afterburner-2.8.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.195/h2-1.4.195.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.7.0/springfox-swagger2-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.13/swagger-annotations-1.5.13.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.13/swagger-models-1.5.13.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.7.0/springfox-spi-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.7.0/springfox-core-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.7.0/springfox-schema-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.7.0/springfox-swagger-common-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.7.0/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.11/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-bean-validators/2.7.0/springfox-bean-validators-2.7.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j/2.0.0/liquibase-slf4j-2.0.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/ryantenney/metrics/metrics-spring/3.1.3/metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.0/HikariCP-2.6.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.42/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-envers/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-envers-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.5.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-jdk8-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.15/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.15/tomcat-juli-8.5.15.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.6.6/byte-buddy-1.6.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.25/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.25/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-
4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-messaging/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-messaging-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/com/alibaba/druid/1.1.2/druid-1.1.2.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-
4.5.3.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-undertow/1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-undertow-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/qk/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.4.15.Final/undertow-core-
   ...
    2017-08-09 10:52:02.578  INFO 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.ApiApp                  : Starting ApiApp on qk with PID 5916 (/Users/qk/myosgit/api/target/classes started by qk in /Users/qk/myosgit/api)
   s.pms.api.config.MetricsConfiguration  : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.573 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering CORS filter
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.765  INFO 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.765 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Initializing Metrics registries
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.769 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering Metrics Filter
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.769 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Registering Metrics Servlet
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.772 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Initialize H2 console
    2017-08-09 10:52:06.772  INFO 5916 --- [  restartedMain] com.sgcc.pms.api.config.WebConfigurer    : Web application fully configured
    2017-08-09 10:52:07.304 DEBUG 5916 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.p.api.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : Configuring Liquibase
    2017-08-09 10:52:07.317  WARN 5916 --- [ api-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
    2017-08-09 10:52:09.137 DEBUG 5916 --- [ api-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 1819 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml of the project you need to enable debugging.

This line is commented you need to uncomment it. Eg:

```
 <!-- Enable the line below to have remote debugging of your application on port 5005-->
<jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I just open this project by command line "idea ." . I just deleted the project from the IDEA,and import as a maven project in IDEA